# How to overwrite value in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext in my app, which accepts only numbers. It is set to 0 by default. But when i enters some umbers, i want to overwrite the initial 0 in the left. Now i am having some problem with edittext. For example, when i inserts a 1, i want it to how 1, not 01. my code is like,

```
    value = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.value);
    value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
        {   
            if(arg0.length()==0)
            {
                value.setText("0");
                int i = value.getText().length();
                value.setSelection(i);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

How can i achieve it? or is it possible?

Comment: Is the **0** shown initially a hint? If it is a hint, set the property **android:hint="0"** for the EditText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `android:hint` in your xml file.

For example,

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/value"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="0"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of options to accomplish what you're looking for. Besides the ones already mentioned, I'd say the EditText's attribute [`android:selectAllOnFocus="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aselectAllOnFocus) might be worth looking at. It's convenient for a default value, and at the same quite user friendly as changing the value does not require any 'backspacing'.

Answer (score 0):

You can change string to empty in your beforeTextChanged Function Call and let the onTextChanged as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  value.setText("0");
use value.setHint("0");

Answer (score 0):

Use setHint(int) method to display 0 initially. So that when the user types something it is automatically cleared and you can get the text as desired.